# How can i remove duplicate set statement?

Tags: vba, solidworks

Recently, I studying VBA to automating some solidworks work. I wrote following code.

```
Option Explicit

Dim swApp As SldWorks.SldWorks

Sub main()
    Set swApp = Application.SldWorks
    Call createNewPartDoc
    'Some code here
End Sub

Sub createNewPartDoc()
    Set swApp = Application.SldWorks
    'Some code here for create new part document
End Sub
```

Then, I noticed some duplicated code.

How can I remove duplicate code (`Set swApp = Application.SldWorks`) in createNewPartDoc subroutine or other subroutines?

Comment: if `main` and `createNewPartDoc` are located in the same module, you don't, you can remove from `Sub createNewPartDoc()` as it is already set in `main` which is calling the routine

Comment: I personally won't use a global object `swApp` to store a reference to an already global object `Application.SldWorks` .

Answer (score 1):

Just pass swApp as argument:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim swApp As SldWorks.SldWorks
    Set swApp = Application.SldWorks
    Call createNewPartDoc(swApp)
    'Some code here
End Sub

Sub createNewPartDoc(App As SldWorks.SldWorks)
    'Some code here for create new part document
End Sub
```